# passar um array de objetos para uma outra página

Tags: php, javascript, array

```
            scoreBoard.push({
                acertosOuErros: acertoOuErro,
                multiplicacao: resultado
            });
```

Este é a minha array feita em javascript, queria passar essa array de objetos para uma outra página para eu trata-la (iria montar uma tabela de resultados), vi que existem vários métodos (via cookie, via url, via form em hidden), mas queria saber manda-lo via ajax (acho que é a melhor forma, não é?). poderiam me ensinar? estou querendo aprender.

**Vi um tutorial em outro lugar, mas não entendi muito bem.
Essa Array (dataString) é o exemplo montado pelo site.


Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
    var dataString = {
        'id':'1',
        'name':'peter parker',
        'age':'unknown',
        'role':'spiderman'
    }
    $.ajax({
         url: "result.php",
         data: {'data':dataString}, 
         type: "POST",
         cache: false,
         success: function(response){
         alert("ok");
         $('#test').html(response);
        }
     });
   })
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click Me</a>
<div id="test"></div>
```

**result.php**

```
$data = ($_POST['data']);

foreach($data as $d){
    echo stripslashes($d);
}
```

Nesse exemplo, o array é enviado via ajax para result.php e é retornado uma string para página anterior? E como eu faço para enviar a minha array de objetos para uma outra página? eu iria montar uma tabela com essa array enviada pela página anterior...

Comment: Acho que você só precisa serializar o seu array e mandar normalmente por ajax. Substitua o `{'data':dataString}` pelo seu array já serializado.

Comment: eu queria mexer nessa array em outra página (result.php), naquele exemplo é retornado o array de novo para a mesma página que enviou a array. tem algo a ver com aquela função success? eu queria redirecionar para a página result.php e mexer os dados lá.

Comment: no ajax, você não vai trocar de página, ele vai mandar o seu array() por um $_POST, então ele ira executar tudo que você mandar fazer dentro da `result.php` em segundo plano. Quando ele terminar ira pegar como retorno o echo que você der na pagina `result.php`. o success é a parte que pega esse retorno

Comment: O único jeito de você trocar de página enviando um $_POST é através de um formulário.

Answer (score -1):

eu acho que onde tens data: `{'data':dataString}`, alteras dataString para o nome do teu array...

Comment: esse exemplo funcionou, mas a dúvida é outra: eu queria mexer nessa array em outra página (result.php), naquele exemplo é retornado o resultado de novo para a mesma página que enviou a array. o que eu preciso modificar no código para fazer isso ?